# Python Pandas: float values break down when df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have a dataframe with trades. I want to get from this OHLCV.

When I aggregate for this, I get a multi-index dataframe. When I drop the level from multi-index through the assignment of columns, extra characters appear on the floating-point tail.

```
import pandas as pd

trades = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'price': np.random.uniform(1000, 1200, 48),
        'volume': np.random.uniform(50, 100, 48)
    },
    index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00', end='2019-01-02 23:00', freq='H')
)

ohlcv = trades.resample('D').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})
# ohlcv['volume'].iloc[0] == 1744.871219

ohlcv.columns = ohlcv.columns.droplevel()
# ohlcv['volume'].iloc[0] == 1744.8712193218892
```

- How to remove the level of multi-index so that the floating-point
  numbers do not change?
  or
- How to aggregate the initial dataframe without generating a multi-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not changed values, only are not displayed, because first `iloc` return one value `Series`:

```
np.random.seed(456)
trades = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'price': np.random.uniform(1000, 1200, 48),
        'volume': np.random.uniform(50, 100, 48)
    },
    index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00', end='2019-01-02 23:00', freq='H') )

ohlcv = trades.resample('D').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})
print (ohlcv)
                  price                                              volume
                   open         high          low        close       volume
2019-01-01  1049.751182  1177.140381  1001.636683  1001.636683  1777.630832
2019-01-02  1072.013700  1194.631131  1008.525926  1130.678109  1804.651706

print (ohlcv['volume'].iloc[0])
volume    1777.630832
Name: 2019-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64

print (ohlcv['volume'].iloc[0].tolist())
[1777.630832239808]

ohlcv.columns = ohlcv.columns.droplevel()
print (ohlcv['volume'].iloc[0])
1777.630832239808
```

Another solution for remove `MultiIndex` is `map` with `join`:

```
ohlcv.columns = ohlcv.columns.map('_'.join)
print (ohlcv)
             price_open   price_high    price_low  price_close  volume_volume
2019-01-01  1049.751182  1177.140381  1001.636683  1001.636683    1777.630832
2019-01-02  1072.013700  1194.631131  1008.525926  1130.678109    1804.651706
```

Solution with [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) is possible use too, but be careful for avoid return duplicated column names:

```
ohlcv = trades.resample('D').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'ohlc'})
print (ohlcv)
                  price                                            volume  \
                   open         high          low        close       open   
2019-01-01  1049.751182  1177.140381  1001.636683  1001.636683  68.335978   
2019-01-02  1072.013700  1194.631131  1008.525926  1130.678109  85.631147   


                 high        low      close  
2019-01-01  98.772905  50.545352  70.416061  
2019-01-02  99.011524  51.194741  57.057429  

ohlcv.columns = ohlcv.columns.droplevel()
print (ohlcv)
                   open         high          low        close       open  \
2019-01-01  1049.751182  1177.140381  1001.636683  1001.636683  68.335978   
2019-01-02  1072.013700  1194.631131  1008.525926  1130.678109  85.631147   

                 high        low      close  
2019-01-01  98.772905  50.545352  70.416061  
2019-01-02  99.011524  51.194741  57.057429 

print (ohlcv['open'])
                   open       open
2019-01-01  1049.751182  68.335978
2019-01-02  1072.013700  85.631147
```

Comment: Thanks. How to make resample().agg() correctly summed?  Why do tails appear?

trades = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'price': np.random.uniform(1000, 1200, 48).round(4),
        'volume': np.random.uniform(50, 100, 48).round(4)
    },
    index=pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00', end='2019-01-02 23:00', freq='H')
)
# trades['volume'].sum().tolist() == **3416.5026**

ohlcv = trades.resample('D').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})
# ohlcv['volume'].iloc[0].tolist() == **[1771.6999000000003]**

Comment: @vvnykt - Not understand, do you want same values?

Comment: Not. I thought that agg() adds tails, unlike sum(). It turns out both do so sometimes depending on the summed values. This topic is closed, the question is beyond its scope. I will look about rounding in Python.

Comment: @vvnykt - Do you think `print(trades['volume'].sum().tolist())`  vs `ohlcv = trades.resample('D').agg({'price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'}) 
print(ohlcv['volume'].sum().tolist())` ? Why is difference?

Comment: The sum at once may not coincide with the sum of the parts. I think this is somehow related to the representation of python's float in the machine and the result may not be accurate. For example, why np.random.random(2).round(4).sum() sometimes gives a number with a another numbers of digits after the point?

Comment: @vvnykt - I think you are right, there are float accurace problems. Btw, was my answer helpful? Or rather remove it?

Comment: Yes, was helpful. I thought that a problem occurs when drop a level. Thank you!